# Integrate multiple forms as optional steps in one form

Tags: forms, information-architecture, workflow

**Context**

I'm working on a CMS portal that supports content in a set of categories. The categories important for this questions are in particular;

- Media
- Pages

When adding media, the users has to complete a form containing the following fields in a one page form;

- media
- title
- description (optional)
- tags (optional)

**The problem**

The problem I'm facing is that pages also can contain media. Users can add existing media from a list, but also add new media right there from the add-page-form.

I'm struggling to find a good flow of doing so. I've thought of a few ways so far which all have some pros and cons;

- 'Add media' is a button in the form that shows a **dialog** with the add-media-form;

The form is quite long to put in a dialog. This is also inconsistent with other forms.

- 'add media' is a button that takes the user to a **second page in the form;**

I'm not sure if having a multi-page-form is good UX. Especially since the user will return to page one upon completing the add-media-form-page.

- add the add-media-form to the add-page-form **in the same page;**

This will increase the form length significantly. It's also problematic since it's quite a long form for an optional step.

- allow drag-and-drop/click-to-upload media **without the add-media-form.**

This way users can upload media without the required fields which will just make a mess.

**Question**

What is the best way to integrate multiple forms as optional steps in one form?

Comment: On a media list, would you also want to indicate in a details view that a particular piece of media is currently associated with a page? What is the purpose of a page in this context, or is it a generic object a user can edit any way they choose?

Comment: Yes. I would want that. The purpose of a page in this context to show an example of how two different categories of content can integrate in the process of adding content. The page is generic. Users can add anything to it ranging from plain text to media players.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep tasks separate and name them in a way that reflects the available actions. This looks longer but may simplify the use of CMS.

By selecting **Media management** or **Media manager** we go to the section/page were we **upload** assets, **organize** them into virtual libraries/lists and **edit** their data (title, etc).

In the **Add/edit a page** section we can **Add a media** from the library/list of existing media to a new page.

By selecting **Add a media** here, the list of existing media is available to the user. (He/she can't upload, edit, organize media here, just add a media).

Optional: An **upload new** (media) next to the list will take us to **Media managment**.

Answer (score 0):

Media page will archive all your media. Admin can upload, delete, etc, en essence manage all the media assets which will be accessible from other pages in the CMS. For example:
[image]

Pages will have an add media button. Open a dialog box to choose from the Media archive. You don't have to provide them full media table with attributes, etc. Just thumbnails of the media will do. Enough for Admin to identify the image and pick it.

Provide search, and upload / drag and drop option to add new media directly in the dialog box. If admin cannot find their media, they can upload directly from dialog without having to cut their workflow.

[image]